# How can I get query value after the syntax # in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Now I have a URL:http://xxx.com:22683/Default.aspx?id=1#para=msg
How can I get the part of "para=msg" by using asp.net,not JavaScript?I know that JS can make it.

Thanks.

Comment: using `Request.QueryString` ?

Comment: It doesn't work.It throws exception of System.NullReferenceException

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
//string id = Request.QueryString["id"];
//string msg =  Request.QueryString["para"]; 
var param1 =
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(url.Substring(
    new []{0, url.IndexOf('#')}.Max()
)).Get("para");
```

Comment: You have to remove # and add &

Comment: Sorry,but I just want to get anchor value from current URL.

Comment: I have edited my code. check it. I am not sure but check it once

Comment: If I write like this:
var URL = new Uri("http://localhost:22683/Default.aspx?id=1#para=msg");
string p = URL.Fragment;
I can get anchor value,too.But now I must write it in Page_Load,even if current url is "http://localhost:22683/Default.aspx?id=1#para=msg",the value of Request.Url is "http://localhost:22683/Default.aspx?id=1",no "para=msg",so your code doesn' work. :(

Comment: I mean it's lost "para=msg",Request.Url is just "localhost:22683/Default.aspx?id=1"

Comment: You have to check for that parameter.